# org-mode quote block environment

Tags: org-export, latex

Is there a way in org-mode to setup

```
#+begin_quote
my quote here
#+end_quote
```

to be expanded in latex export as

```
\begin{quoting}
...
\end{quoting}
```

I want to use quoting latex package to style quote blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use a special block. In your case:

```
#+begin_quoting
my quote here
#+end_quoting
```

Will be exported as

```
\begin{quoting}
my quote here
\end{quoting}
```

You can also modify the attributes of an example block to accomplish the same thing:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment quoting
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
My quote here
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

The relevant manual page is [(org) LaTeX specific attributes](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Example-blocks-in-LaTeX-export)